# Use Polar SDK in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality

I am very inexperienced and have trouble using the Polar SDK (https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk) in Unity.
My task is to display the data from the Polar H10 chest strap and the Polar Verity Sense armband on the Oculus Quest 2, and I have to develop the VR app with Unity.

**Tried Approaches**

I have tried the approach suggested here https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusQuest/comments/ffx5se/quest_heartbeat_has_anybody_found_a_decent/.

> use the Polar Android SDK, loaded into Unity as an aar

Therefore I installed Android Studio and tried to compile the SDK to an aar without any success.

Also, I tried to follow the readme for installation (https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk#installation).

> In build.gradle make sure the minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher.

There are so many build.gradle files that I am not sure which one I have to take because none of them really fit?

**Additional Question**: Is it possible to use the Polar API to display data from the Polar Unite Watch in an Oculus Quest 2 App built with Unity?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me because at this point I am just confused and don't know how to proceed further. Thank you in advance!